# Texture used as FBO color attachment and sampler2D of a shader program at the same time

Tags: opengl, textures, fbo

I have created an FBO and have a texture bound as its color attachment, and I have multiple shader programs that do some post processing on the texture, everything works great, but it does not make sense to me that the texture can be used as the input(sampler2D) as well as the output of the shaders **at the same time**.

Following are the steps I have taken:

1. Create an FBO `fboA`.
2. Create a texture `textureA`, and bind it as color attachment of `fboA`.
3. Call `glBindFrameBuffer` to bind `fboA` to the framebuffer target.
4. Call `glUseProgram` to use shader program `shaderA`.
5. Call `glDrawArrays` to draw something (eventually drawn on `textureA` because `fboA` is currently bound).
6. Call `glUseProgram` to use shader program `shaderB` which has a `sampler2D` uniform in the fragment shader.
7. Bind `textureA` as `sampler2D` uniform of shader program `shaderB`.
8. In the fragment shader, `textureA` is used to set the `fragColor`.

What I am confused about is the last two steps, where `textureA` is used as the input of the fragment shader, still it is bound to the current framebuffer. This appears to me that the fragment shader is reading from and writing to the same piece of memory, isn't this some kind of undefined behaviors, why it still works correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> isn't this some kind of undefined behaviors, why it still works correctly?

Because "[undefined behavior](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Memory_Model#Framebuffer_objects)" does not preclude the possibility that the behavior may appear to "work correctly". UB means *anything* can happen, including the thing you actually wanted to happen.

Of course, it might suddenly stop "working" tomorrow. Or when you take your code to a different GPU. Or if you start rendering more stuff. Or if you breath on your computer really hard.

Undefined behavior is *undefined*.

If you want to make it well-defined, then you need to use [texture barrier](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Texture_Barrier) functionality and abide by its rules: no more than one read/modify/write per-fragment between barriers, or just read from and write to non-overlapping sets of fragments.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I wanted to know. Also I was just pointed to [Feedback Loops](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Framebuffer_Object#Feedback_Loops).